# Can you Disengage while you are in darkness?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, opportunity-attack, vision-and-light

When I read the rules, it is not written that the Disengage Action relies on sight, but Opportunity Attacks do.

Imagine that you are facing a spider, and a wizard casts the *Darkness* spell. You know the spider is in front of you, but can you Disengage from it if you can't see it anymore ?

Answer (score 31):

### Yes

In 5e you don't disengage "from" someone. Instead, you just don't provoke OAs when you move:

> If you take the Disengage action, your Movement doesn’t provoke Opportunity Attacks for the rest of the turn.

You definitely can take the Disengage action if you don't see any enemies. Moreover, you can Disengage without enemies at all. The only requirement for Disengage is your ability to take an Action.

Answer (score 13):

#### Yes

You can disengage as an action on any turn whether you can see the other creature or not. Keep in mind that if the creature cannot see you because of the darkness then they wouldn't get OA anyway. However, if the creature can see in magical darkness then they would still get the OA unless you disengage.

Comment: Good point about the requirement to see the target in order to take an Attack of Opportunity. If the spider in the example is a giant spider or giant wolf spider, it will have 10 feet of blindsight, so it would get to take the AoO unless the Disengage action was taken.